# Differential transceiver SN65C1167

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, power-electronics, differential, mosfet-driver

I have a question about a differential transceiver.

In my application I am using a MCU to generate PWM signals for a gate driver board (CGD1200HB2P-BM2). This board, however, needs a diffierential PWM signal.

I checked the circuit and the gate driver board is using a differential transceiver (SN65C1167).

Unfortunately, I never worked with this type of PWM signal before, which is why I am a bit confused: do I really need a differential PWM signal with +5V level and -5V level or would it work if I have a PWM signal with +5V and GND

See picture of PWM signals:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you really do need a differential PWM signal if you want to use the differential pins (inputs 3-10) on the CGD1200HB2P-BM2.

The Threshold voltage is shown in the Gate Driver Electrical Characterization:
[image]

You need to have a differential voltage below -200mV and above -7V in order for the 0 to be detected.